# Triying to replace line in PHP with SED

Tags: php, linux, sed

I want to replace this:

```
<li><a href="autor.php?<?=$a?>">Autor</a></li>
```

to:

```
<li><a href="autor.php?<?=$a?>">Autor</a></li><li><a href="QTY.php?<?=$a?>">QTY</a></li>
```

With this code:

```
find www/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/\"\<li\>\<a href=\"autor.php\?\<\?\=\$a?\>\"\>Autor\<\/a\>\<\/li\>\"\/\"\<li\>\<a href=\"autor.php\?\<\?=\$a\?>\">Autor\<\/a\>\<\/li\>\<li\>\<a href=\"QTY.php\?\<\?=\$a\?\>\"\>QTY\<\/a\>\<\/li\>\"/g' {} \;
```

And i get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 211: unterminated `s' command
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are escaping the "delimiter" (in the first case `/`, in the second case `-` ) so that sed doesn't interpret it as it should. Try replacing the intermediate `\-` by a `-` .

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for the 's' command is:

```
s/foo/bar/
```

but you only have two '/' characters in the string that aren't escaped.

I'd recommend you recompose your substitution using a different separator. I.e. you can just as well use:

```
s-foo-bar-
```

Comment: I use: find www/ -type f -exec sed -i 's-\"\<li\>\<a href=\"autor.php\?\<\?\=\$a?\>\"\>Autor\<\/a\>\<\/li\>\"\-\"\<li\>\<a href=\"autor.php\?\<\?=\$a\?>\">Autor\<\/a\>\<\/li\>\<li\>\<a href=\"QTY.php\?\<\?=\$a\?\>\"\>QTY\<\/a\>\<\/li\>\"-g' {} \; and i get the same error .

Comment: You changed the separator character but you're still escaping the middle separator (i.e. '\-'). That makes it "not a separator"

Answer (score 0):

```
find www/ -type f -exec \
  sed -i '\#<li><a href="autor.php?<?=\$a?>">Autor</a></li># { 
             s##&<li><a href="QTY.php?<?=\$a?>">QTY</a></li>#
             }' {} \;
```

- Could be a one liner by removing `{}` in sed action and `\`. Use it for *clarity*
- use the another separator than `/` for ease in sed action avoiding escaping this character (`#` here).
- use a pattern matching before the `s///` action but could also directly be done (also for clarity). I use the `s//` behaviour  for this , where `//` mean, last regex researched, and also the `&` inside the replacment pattern (found pattern content)

Answer (score 0):

Just use string opeartors instead of a regexp and a "special" sed replacement pattern:

```
$ cat file
foo<li><a href="autor.php?<?=$a?>">Autor</a></li>bar

$ awk -v tgt='<li><a href="autor.php?<?=$a?>">Autor</a></li>' \
      -v add='<li><a href="QTY.php?<?=$a?>">QTY</a></li>' '
           s=index($0,tgt) { $0 = substr($0,1,s+length(tgt)-1) add substr($0,s+length(tgt)) }
    1' file
foo<li><a href="autor.php?<?=$a?>">Autor</a></li><li><a href="QTY.php?<?=$a?>">QTY</a></li>bar
```